# issue with Codeigniter .htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

got this in my `.htaccess` file (as said in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) and the `apache` settings for virtual host look like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fitness.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias www.fitness.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blast

    <Directory /var/www/blast>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Yet if I want to go to `http://fitness.local/events` it's not working, but `http://fitness.local/index.php/events` is working. I have enabled mod rewrite for apache, so that's also covered.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you remove 'index.php' in your config?

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes I did and that didn't fix it.

Comment: did you restart server after enable mod_rewrite?

Comment: @MuhammadRashid yes I did that and that didn't help either.

Comment: try setting `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` in your config.php

Answer (score 0):

try this in your .htacess file then run

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but this doesn't really fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    RewriteBase /dude_code/

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
    RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteCond $1 ^(main\.php|index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

    # No rewriting
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe I should place the .htaccess file somewhere else or smthn? :D

Comment: RewriteBase /dude_code/  
change dude_code to the full path of your code at htdocs

Comment: By that you mean for example...?

Comment: No I ment could you please show me an example with the path - i.e. `/var/www/blast` or what kind of a path should I give it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Open your httpd conf file check if mod-rewrite is enabled

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
AllowOverride All
```

Then restart your Httpd.

This always works in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess to your project.

(Should be place **outside of Application Folder**)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```